# RPT with virtual users

Tags: virtual, rpt

I am working on Rational performance tester (RPT) to do some load testing for one particular functionality. I recorded the script and I ran the same , it works fine without any errors. But when I run the same with 5 virtual users ( Performance schedule), there were lot of Error occurs around 14- 16 . It displays 1 FAIL verdict reported. I am not sure why the working script suddenly fails when I impose some load..

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze and perform the correlation for each requests. Not all users share the same session id (an example) in the real-world. Refer this link to learn about [Data Correlation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.common.doc/topics/cdatacorr.html).